# Is it right "Smile in love"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

If a person is in love with someone, can I say that she has got a smile in love?
I need it in a sentence where smile (or a synonymous) is the subject and "in love" (or a synonymous) is the attribute.

EDIT: or "loving smile" perhaps? Here loving means "of a person in love" or just "cute"?

MORE EDIT: this is a sentence I wrote in italian, that I'm trying to render in english: "ci si può annoiare di tutto, tranne che di un sorriso innamorato". Google Translator says: "you can get bored of everything but a smile in love". Innamorato usually requires a person, as in "woman in love". In this case it stands for "... but a smile of someone in love".

As "sorriso innamorato" is more poetic than "sorriso di qualcuno innamorato", I ask if there is a similar shorter form in english

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Can you please include your own [research](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (e.g. which dictionary definition of 'loving' you found and where) so we offer better answers to your question.

Comment: I'd suggest  "she's got the smile of love"

Comment: Your edited suggestions are much better, including 'the smile of a person/  of someone in love.' In Br English cute would be somewhat patronising.

Comment: @Hugh re-edited the question to give the exact context. "of someone in love" is what I meant, now wonder if there is a shorter form

Comment: The Italian vesion is more poetic, if this is for a woman, keep the original. I guarantee she will be wooed. Otherwise try this " You can be weary (bored) of anything in life, except for the smile of someone who is in love (OR a lover's smile)"

Comment: Thanks Mari-Lou, lover's smile is probably the best form. What subtle differences between the two languages! "Sorriso" as an abstract name has the masculine gender in italian but is valid for both gender, while "il sorriso di un innamorato" is the smile of a male in love because of the final -o.

Answer (score 5):

"Smile in love" doesn't sound quite right.

"Loving smile" could refer to a mother's smile as she gazes at her child, so perhaps that is too general.

My suggestions: "love-struck," "infatuated," or "besotted" smile. These are all synonyms for "in love."

Comment: These are good in description; not ideal in a letter or post, though.

Answer (score 1):

I can see using 'She smiled with love' which is very similar in meaning although not identical. This is a very context dependent question in my opinion.